# How can I rotate an image around an arbitrary point on a canvas, which can then be moved and rotated again?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, geometry

I am trying to rotate an image drawn onto an HTML canvas element on a map, around the centre point of a masked area.
The image extent is defined by [minX, minY, maxX, maxY].
The masked area can be resized to any size within the extent of the image.

The position of the image on the canvas is first calculated:

```
// width / height of image from points (x/y coordinates)
c = imageExtent[2] - imageExtent[0];
d = imageExtent[3] - imageExtent[1];

// converted to canvas units
const scaledWidth = c / resolution * pixelRatio;
const scaledHeight = d / resolution * pixelRatio;

// offset of image extent from canvas extent for positioning image in centre
const x1 = (imageExtent[0] - canvasExtent[0]) / resolution * pixelRatio;
const y1 = (canvasExtent[3] - imageExtent[3]) / resolution * pixelRatio;
```

The image can then be drawn in the centre of the canvas and rotated:

```
ctx.translate(offsetX + scaleX / 2, offsetY + scaleY / 2);
// Rotate around this point
ctx.rotate(angle);
// Draw the image centered on this point
ctx.drawImage(image, -scaledWidth / 2, -scaledHeight / 2, scaledWidth , scaledHeight);
```

[image]

When the masked area is added, the centre point of this area becomes the point of rotation and the following code is used to draw and rotate the image.

```
// Calculate the center of the maskExtent
const maskCenterX = (maskExtent[0] + maskExtent[2]) / 2;
const maskCenterY = (maskExtent[1] + maskExtent[3]) / 2;

// Calculate the distance from the imageExtent corner to the mask center
const distToMaskCenterX = maskCenterX -imageExtent[0];
const distToMaskCenterY = imageExtent[3] - maskCenterY;

// Convert these distances to canvas pixels
const canvasDistX = distToMaskCenterX / resolution * pixelRatio;
const canvasDistY = distToMaskCenterY / resolution * pixelRatio;

// Translate to the center of the crop extent (considering the original offset)
ctx.translate(x1 + canvasDistX, y1 + canvasDistY);

// Rotate around this point
ctx.rotate(rotate);

// Draw the image such that the crop center is the rotation pivot
ctx.drawImage(image, -canvasDistX, -canvasDistY, scaledWidth , scaledHeight);
```

[image]

The problem comes about when the image is being masked from an already rotated position.
When the masked area is calculated, an extent in the same form as the image extent is retrieved.
The image is currently shifting when drawing based on the above calculations.
How can I ensure the image is drawn and rotated around the expected positions e.g. as shown below?
[image]